# Completium-cli setMockupNow

Tags: testing

I write tests using completium-cli and jest. All the tests I wrote work correctly, except one. It requires waiting for X  blocks (X=3 in current example) and calling entrypoint with the valid parameters. Tried to use `setMockupNow(now+3000)`, but the contract throws an error `"GAME_NOT_ENDED"`, even that 3000s == 100 blocks, so setMockupNow doesn't work as expected.

test.js - endpoint and init setMockupNow details:

```
  setEndpoint('mockup')
  jest.setTimeout(30000);

  // Mockup Time
  const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  
  setMockupNow(now)
```

test.js - failed test

```
test('Game ended', async () => {
  var after = now + 3000;
  console.log("Now: ", now);
  console.log("After: ", after);
  setMockupNow(after);

  var op = await room.end_game({
    arg:{
      room_idb: "NYC",
      serverid: "NYC",
      packed_outcome: PACKED_OUTCOME,
      signed_outcome: SIGNED_OUTCOME
    }, as: bob.pkh
  })
  })
```

console output

```
console.log
    Now:  1670511829

      at Object.log (__tests__/test_room.js:199:11)

  console.log
    After:  1670514829

      at Object.log (__tests__/test_room.js:200:11)

 FAIL  __tests__/test_room.js (15.027 s)
  ✓ Contract deployed (2265 ms)
  ✓ Server created (1092 ms)
  ✓ Room filled (3697 ms)
  ✓ Refund after game started (1098 ms)
  ✓ Game still active (1141 ms)
  ✓ Player not inside room (1105 ms)
  ✓ Room not exist on this server (1093 ms)
  ✓ Wrong server (1070 ms)
  ✕ Game ended (1457 ms)

  ● Game ended

    thrown: Object {
      "value": "\"GAME_STILL_ACTIVE\"",
    }
```

contract.arl - require entrypoint part

```
entry end_game (room_idb : string, serverid : string, packed_outcome : bytes, signed_outcome : signature) {
    require {
        r7: server.contains(serverid) otherwise "WRONG_SERVER";
        r8: server[serverid].players.contains(caller) otherwise "NOT_PARTICIPATED";
        r9: server[serverid].rooms.contains(room_idb) otherwise "NO_ROOM_ON_THIS_SERVER";
        r10: level > room[room_idb].finish_block otherwise "GAME_STILL_ACTIVE";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually in mockup mode, the way `setMockupNow` works does not increase block level. Fortunately a way to increase the block level is by manually calling the baking process. We have added the call `mockup_bake()` that will invoke the underlying bake process and increase block level by 1. It is available in version `0.4.52` of completium-cli.

Hence in your code, in order to move 100 blocks forwards you will need something like:

```
for(let i=0; i < 100; i++) {
  await mockup_bake()
}
```

The drawback is that it will take a bit less that a one minute ...

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have enough stack exchange reputation to comment on your post so I'll just leave this as an answer (even though it isn't much of an answer).

There was a bug fix on setmockupnow just a few days ago so its probably worth just confirming that you have updated to the latest version of everything - just in case that fixes your problem (best delete package-lock.json as well as node modules before you run `npm i`  as there have been some recent bug fixes associated with dependencies also)